# Flash banner blend effect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timeline

I know that I can find this on google, but I'm in a hurry. Is there a way to blend frames in flash with AS? I'm working on a flash banner, with 3 frames, each containing animations and stuff. My client wants to see different blending effects and all I could find on google was complicated timeline sollutions. Is there a way to solve this with code?

Comment: maybe something like this: http://lostinactionscript.com/2009/05/26/custom-blend-modes-for-flash-10/

Comment: No my question is more basic than this: I know how to blend out a display object for example. But I want to blend from one frame into another. Similar to the way I would use gotoAndPlay().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all 3 movieclips containing animations on the same frame.

Set two of the objects opacity to 0.

Use code (I recommend TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) to animate the opacity of the objects to create cross-fades.

E.g.

```
TweenLite.to(objectOne, 2, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(objectTwo, 2, {alpha:1});
```

Comment: OK, thx. Thats exactly what I did. I just thought, there would be a more elegant solution. I wanted to keep the frames separated, because its much more organised.

Comment: One man's organisation is another mans chaos. As far as I know cross fading the objects on separate frames is impossible, as the rendering engine can only display one frame of an object at any given time.